# Creating ASP.net MVC C# application without using built in Visual Studio Scaffolding templates

Tags: .net

first wish you a great weekend ahead am completely new to this stackoverflow the reason am here is am developing a technical Forum for my final year project and has decided to use ASP.net MVC and MYSQL but my problem is
1: visual studio 2010 provides some inbuilt  Scaffolding templates for creating a empty     view or list view etc(i.e right click on action->create view).i don't want to use them but can i develop my own views without using their templates.? 
2: and if i create such how can i proceed with controllers or models to perform CURD operations i.e for instance i write my own view how to code it for buttons,textbox etc 
3: can someone let me a good tutorials or good site for such stuff i.e **building web application in asp.net MVC without templates** i.e from basic scratch a basic MVC Tutorials which help me in CURD and other operations
please suggest me some thing as am running out of time and need to work i will thank
full 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can absolutely 100% build ASP.NET MVC applications without using MVC's "scaffolding" feature for views and controllers. All the scaffolding does is automate tasks that you could do yourself. In fact, it can be a great way to learn MVC too. If you want to learn how to do CRUD operations in an MVC web app, I do suggest trying out the "Add Controller" feature in MVC and check out what it generates for the controller, the database context, and the views.

**MVC4:**

To help learn MVC4 there is a FREE 10-module series of videos on the official ASP.NET MVC web site. Check them out here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4

**MVC3:**

Similarly, there is also a series of FREE videos for MVC3, available here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight

And specifically for data, check out this video: http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Comment: thanks @Eilon for your time and answer its really great but can u suggest me some MVC3 tutorials based on my requirement or else the way to google it please

Comment: @sam I added links to the MVC3 videos. For the most part data access is the same between MVC3 and MVC4, especially if you do it manually, without the "scaffolding" feature.

Comment: @sam if you feel the answer is correct, please mark it as "Accepted". That will make it easier for others to find answers to their own questions.